# ANOVA and post-hoc analysis using R when we only have means and SD of three populations

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc

I want to perform an ANOVA using R. I have three populations, represented by their respective means and SD:
Pop.1: 5.5 +- 0.4 (n=100)
Pop.2: 5.9 +- 0.3 (n=150)
Pop.3: 6.2 +- 0.5 (n=200)

Which is the exact code using R to perform the ANOVA using exclusively these data?

Moreover, how can I perfom subsequently a post-hoc analysis?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What specific post-hoc comparisons do you want to make? If it's all 3 of them then your ANOVA is pointless.

Comment: If you have *population* means and sds you don't need statistical inference at all - the population means plainly differ. Statistical inference (like ANOVA) is used when you want to make inferences about populations but you have *samples*. If you mean something different from what you asked, you'll need to edit your question.

Comment: In the same way that a T-test can be performed by using exclusively mean, SD and n, I supposed that an ANOVA could be as well performed in someway. How about simulating those data?

Comment: Assuming that you refer to samples rather than populations, it seems that it is necessary to have the original data in order to fill the ANOVA table. A workaround probably is to create random data from the assumed underlying distributions of each samples and apply F test in these data.

Comment: Otherwise, John, what about a Bonferroni or Tukey tests?

Answer (score 1):

R does basic math calculations (`?Math`) and you can just look up [online](http://people.wku.edu/david.neal/statistics/advanced/anova.html) the math to solve your problem. To get the the criterion of *F* value for the test statistic you can use the function `qf`. Post hoc tests are similar in the sense that the math and equations are easy to look up. Perhaps you should update your question with the kind of post hoc test you need and why you want that in particular.

Comment: As Epaminondas say, I have 3 samples, with their means, sd and n. Which is de code to introduce in R and calculate de one-way ANOVA in the example from the top? I checked your link John, but couldn't open the programs. Thanks

Comment: @antecessor Check out the rpsychi package.